FullSimplify not working as desired in Mathematica 11.3
I have the following function in Mathematica:
f[n_] := (Sqrt[n] + Sqrt[n + 16 (Sqrt[n] + 1)])/8 - 
  1/2 (Power[n + Sqrt[n^2 - 1/27]   , (3)^-1] + Power[
     n - Sqrt[n^2 - 1/27], (3)^-1])

Then I took its derivative using:
d[n_]:= f'[n]

Then I tried to simplify the derivative using:
FullSimplify[d[n]]

But as you can see in the attached image, I am not getting a simplified mathematical expression, as both the numerator and denominator are itself in the form of numerator and denominator. Can somebody please tell me how to fix this?


Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. It depends on what final form you want. For example: Is this okay? FullSimplify[Expand[d[n]]]

How about Series[f'[n], {n, Infinity, 1}] which results in $$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}{8}-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2/3}}{3\ 2^{2/3}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{4/3}\right)?$$

@Domen I want answer in the form of $\frac{p_1}{q_1}+\frac{p_2}{q_2}+...+\frac{p_t}{q_t}$, where $p_i$ and $q_i$ are itself not in the form of $\frac{a}{b}$.

Perhaps: Together /@ Simplify[ f'[n]]

Its always an adventure to steer Simplify with rationals of irrationals, because the process ist controlled by counting the leafs of the tree.
By look and try you get
   d[n] // Together // Expand // FullSimplify // Expand 

$$\text{expr}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{9 n-\sqrt{81 n^2-3}}}{2 \sqrt[6]{3} \sqrt{27 n^2-1}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{81 n^2-3}+9 n}}{2 \sqrt[6]{3} \sqrt{27 n^2-1}}+\frac{1}{16 \sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{16 \sqrt{n+16 \sqrt{n}+16}}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+16 \sqrt{n}+16}}$$
Some fractions can be combined
$$\text{Simplify}\left[\text{expr}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{9 n-\sqrt{81 n^2-3}}-\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{81 n^2-3}+9 n}}{2 \sqrt[6]{3} \sqrt{27 n^2-1}}+\frac{\sqrt{n}+8}{16 \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+16 \sqrt{n}+16}}+\frac{1}{16 \sqrt{n}}\right]$$
True


How did you get the last expression within Simplify[expr]? That is exactly what I was looking for. Please share.

In order to put the last two fractions of $expr$ over a common denominator, you have to multiply numerator and denominator by the missing factors,  the first by $\sqrt n$ from the last and the last by 8 from the first denominator.  I see no way to get the term together except by converting Plus to List and add selected elements by force, or by specifying a rule exactly matching the two summands.
